# subversion: getting rid of versioned ".svn" directory

Tags: svn

I don't know exactly how it happened, but I have a versioned ".svn" directory
in my repository. Don't ask me how it got there.
If I tell svn to delete it, it does not want to, since .svn is a reserved argument.

Force does not work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Ok I solved it by `svn rm` ing the parent directory and adding it back in.

Still, If someone knows the clean solution to this, it would be highly appreciated.

CLARIFICATION:

```
svn delete <repo url>/foo/.svn
```

Does not work. I think I tried every simple combination of commands and arguments.
I am pretty sure, that if that is doable, it is a hack.
I know of the method: dump -> modify dump with tool -> reimport
but that is as scary as hell. This is not git, if you whack an svn repo,
you/it stays whacked.

Comment: "Don't ask me how it got there." Well, `svn log` would tell you.

Comment: That is a good idea. 'svn log -v' tells me that it had been added. Not much more to be gleaned from it. Must have done an 'svn add' on its parent directory. It is still strange though, because svn add usually destroys or complains about existing .svn directories.

Comment: here, `svn log` also says who added it, when, and what else was done in the same commit. This usually is enough to understand who had done what. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"svn rm" with a URL seems to work fine, I just tried it (using svn 1.6.5, Mac OS X):

```
$ svn ls -R file:///xxx/testrepo
foo/
foo/.svn/
foo/.svn/baz
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz

$ svn rm -m 'Yes it works.' file:///xxx/testrepo/foo/.svn
Committed revision 6.

$ svn ls -R file:///xxx/testrepo
foo/
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz
```

You can also use "svn mv", no need to delete anything:

```
$ svn ls -R file:///xxx/testrepo
foo/
foo/.svn/
foo/.svn/baz
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz

$ svn mv -m 'Rename works too.' file:///xxx/testrepo/foo/.svn \
    file:///xxx/testrepo/foo/dotsvn
Committed revision 8.

$ svn ls -R file:///xxx/testrepo
foo/
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz
foo/dotsvn/
foo/dotsvn/baz
```

PS. Creating ".svn" directories in svn repositories is easy: just use svn cp or svn mv with URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Just `svn delete` it from  the repository directly, e.g.,

`svn rm -m "removing checked-in .svn" http://myserver/svn/repo/trunk/dir/.svn`

then delete your local copy and `svn update` to retrieve the corrected version.

Comment: This does not work as svn delete does also not accept .svn as parameter. This is what I meant by "If I tell svn to delete it..." in my question text.